# Formula in subtotal fields for Crystal Report Crosstab

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I am using Crosstab in Crystal Report, and would like to know how can I add formula in subtotal fields.

Given an example in the picture, there are subtotals for each class (Tom in Class A, John and Sam in Class B). I want to divide the marks in subtotal by 2, i.e. for Mark 1, subtotal for Class A should be 5 and for Class B should be 13.

Could anyone tell me how to modify the Crosstab formulas to do the above task? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Try using embedded summary

Comment: You want only the subtotals to be divided by 2 but not the values themselves?

Comment: Yes, I just want only the subtotal to be divided by 2.